# Read multiple attributes from XML in QT5

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have XML with structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
            <Element id="123">
                    <Type>Type-of-element</Type>
                    <time>2020-02-20 20:20:20<time>
                    <part name="part1" type="Mech">Back</part>
                    <part name="part2" type="Mech">Back</part>
                    <part name="part3" type="Mech">Front</part>
                    <part name="part4" type="Electric">Side-left</part>
                    <part name="part5" type="Electric">Side-right</part>
                    <part name="part6" type="Electric">Front</part>
            </Element>
```

I wrote this function to read this

```
QXmlStreamReader x(xml);

QString partName;
QString partType;
QString partValue;
unsigned long long int elementID;
QString type;
QString time;

if (x.readNextStartElement()){
    if(x.name()=="Element"){
        elementID=x.attributes().value("id").toULongLong();
        qDebug()<<elementID;
    }
    while(x.readNextStartElement()){
        if(x.name()=="part"){
            partName = x.attributes().value("name").toString();
            partType = x.attributes().value("type").toString();
            partValue = x.readElementText();
            qDebug()<<partName<<" "<<partType<<" "<<partValue;
        }
        else if(x.name()=="Type"){
            type=x.readElementText();
            qDebug()<<type;
        }
        else if(x.name()=="time"){.
            time=x.readElementText();
            qDebug()<<time;
        }
        else{
            qDebug()<<"invalid name: "<<x.name();
        }
    }

}
```

And console print just this:

123
"Type-of-element"
"20020-02-20 20:20:20"

So multiple attributes reading did not work. How I can read this?

Comment: You have a typo: `<time>…<time>` should be `<time>…</time>`. In your original example, the parser reads the `<Type>` element and then fails when reading `<time>`. You should check the QXmlStreamReader for errors.

Answer (score 0):

It was a missing / in < /time> now it works perfectly :)